# How to get the time difference between 2 dates in millisec using JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm going to design an application, in which I need to get the exact time difference between two dates.  Ex:

```
Date1:31/05/2011 12:54:00
Date2:31/05/2011 13:54:00
```

I tried using `getTime()` but I didn't get exact result.

The expected output for the above inputs is `3600000` (60 * 60 * 1000) millisec but I'm getting `46800000` (13 * 60 * 60 * 1000).

When I went through different java forums people are suggesting to use JodaTime.

Still I'm unable to get the exact result.

The timezone on I'm working is London(GMT).

Comment: If you're getting a 13-hour difference instead of a one-hour difference: have you checked it's not 12am vs 1pm when you're performing the calculation?  Something along these lines would be my first thought.

Comment: Also - you should know that London's timezone **is not `GMT`**, it's `Europe/London`.  The two look similar until you come to an edge case (such as daylight savings time), and then you wonder why all your times are off by one hour.

Answer (score 8):

Init two dateTime and use Period :

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2013,9,11,9,58,56);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2013,9,11,9,58,59);
Period p = new Period(dt1, dt2, PeriodType.millis());
```

To get difference in milliseconds :

```
System.out.println(p.getValue(0));
```

Comment: using `p.getMillis()` would be better than referencing the index

Comment: joda-time's Period class (as of joda-time 2.9.9) supports only `int` values in the milliseconds field, so this approach breaks when the difference between the two dates in milliseconds overflows integer storage. To see it break, change `dt1` to be, `dt1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 7):

```
public static long getDiff(Calender cal1, Calender cal2)
{
    return Math.abs(cal1.getTimeInMillis() - cal2.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most efficient way of doing it. +1 for that.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [secondsBetween( )](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Seconds.html#secondsBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.ReadablePartial%29)

> Creates a Seconds representing the number of whole seconds between the
>   two specified partial datetimes.
>   The two partials must contain the same fields, for example you can
>   specify two LocalTime objects.

Parameters:

```
 start - the start partial date, must not be null
    end - the end partial date, must not be null
```

Returns:

```
 the period in seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

JodaTime is using machine time inside. So to find miliseconds, you can use a constant storing LocalDateTime referring to Jan 1, 1970(Because of [UNIX Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time,
>   defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap
>   seconds. Then calculate the difference between your DateTime.

I tried like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LocalDateTime JAN_1_1970 = new LocalDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        DateTime local = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam"));
        DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);

        System.out.println("Europe/Amsterdam milis :" + new Duration(JAN_1_1970.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam")), local).getMillis());
        System.out.println("UTC  milis             :" + new Duration(JAN_1_1970.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC), utc).getMillis());

    }
```

And the result is;

```
Europe/Amsterdam milis :1429695646528
UTC  milis             :1429692046534
```

And [@leonbloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277304/leonbloy) write [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274902/jodatime-converting-time-zoned-date-time-to-millis) a good comment.

> Your local and utc represent the same instants of time, (only with
>   different timezones attached). Hence, getMillis() (which gives the
>   "physical" time interval elapsed from the "instant" corresponding to
>   the unix epoch), must return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Joda is a perfect library but if you need the difference between 2 dates in milliseconds you just should calculate difference between getTime(). If you get wrong results you have some problems with timezones or so. Typically it works.

Comment: "Joda is a perfect library".... look at the implementation of `new DateTime((Date)null)` and then tell me that :)