# Joda Time converting time zoned date time to milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

Can somebody please explain to me why when I try to get the milliseconds of a DateTime with a zone different from my own, it gives me back the milliseconds of my local machine's time zone? I'm looking to get the milliseconds of UTC, but my local settings of the application are set to EST (even though I'm actually in Ireland ;) )

Here's the code:

```
  DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime();

  DateTime local = new DateTime();
  DateTime utc = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
  System.out.println("utc zone = " +utc.getZone());
  System.out.println("UTC time: " + utc);
  long current = utc.getMillis();

  System.out.println("current: " + format.print(current));
  System.out.println("local: " + format.print(local.getMillis()));
```

Here's what it prints:

```
 utc zone = UTC
 UTC time: 2013-08-16T13:36:32.444Z
 current: Aug 16, 2013 9:36:32 AM
 local: Aug 16, 2013 9:36:32 AM
```

Currently, I would have thought it should have the same date time as UTC time?

Comment: Your `local` and `utc` represent the same instants of time, (only with  different timezones attached). Hence, `getMillis()` (which gives the "physical" time interval elapsed from the "instant" corresponding to the unix epoch), must return the same value.

Answer (score 22):

A few points:

- You don't need to call `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  Just pass this:

```java
    DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

- When you call `.getMillis()` the result is *always* in UTC.  Representing time as an integer that is not UTC-based is a bad idea, and not something that Joda Time will provide.  Your assessment that the milliseconds are affected by your local time zone is incorrect.
- The conversion errors are because of how you are calling `format.print`.  When you pass an integer, the default behavior is to use the current time zone, which is you local time.  You can change it like this:

```java
    format.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).print(current)
```

- However, if the intention is to print it as a date string, why go to milliseconds first anyway?  If you pass the original `DateTime`, then its time zone information will be applied automatically.

```java
    format.print(utc)
    format.print(local)
```

Put together, the whole thing would look like this:

```java
DateTime local = new DateTime();
DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);

System.out.println("local zone = " + local.getZone());
System.out.println("  utc zone = " + utc.getZone());

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime();
System.out.println(" local: " + format.print(local));
System.out.println("   utc: " + format.print(utc));
System.out.println("millis: " + utc.getMillis());
```

Comment: "When you call .getMillis() the result is always in UTC" I don't much like that way of putting it. getMillis returns the milliseconds ellapsed from the instant to the Unix epoch instant, no timezones involved in that.

Comment: @leonbloy - Actually, since Joda Time doesn't support leap seconds, the value is not truly the *exact* number of milliseconds elapsed. It is an integer representation of the moment at UTC had their not been any leap seconds.  Just being technically accurate.  For all intent and purpose, you can think of them in either manner.