# Jodatime get milliseconds with offset

Tags: timezone, jodatime, offset

New to JodaTime library, i would like to get a DateTime's milliseconds field with the specified TimeZone's offset.
So far my attempt is:

```
      private DateTimeZone          timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam");
  private long now=new DateTime().withZone(timeZone).getMillis();
```

But i always get the UTC millis, the timezone offset isnt applied,
Is there any way to apply the timezone's offset to the DateTime object?
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: What do you intend to do with these "local" millis? What do you really try to achieve? Normally only UTC-millis are needed.

Anyway, remember the general timezone offset definition which is:

> UTC + Offset = Local Time

Then the solution is simple:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam");
long nowUTC = new DateTime().withZone(tz).getMillis();
long nowLocal = nowUTC + tz.getOffset(nowUTC);
```

But once again: What is your use-case for "local" millis? They are not even related to UNIX epoch any longer because the UTC-link is cut off.

About your last question ("Is there any way to apply the timezone's offset to the DateTime object?"):

Your `DateTime`-object already has got a timezone, namely "Europe/Amsterdam". It is internally used to compute the field tuple representation once you have a global UTC-timestamp expressed as millis since UNIX epoch. No need to apply an extra offset on `DateTime`. It is already there.

Comment: thx meno, i will try this as soon as i get to my machine and let you know

Answer (score 0):

`JodaTime` is using machine time inside. So to find miliseconds, you can use a constant storing  `LocalDateTime` referring to `Jan 1, 1970`(Because of [UNIX Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time,
>   defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap
>   seconds.

Then calculate the difference between your DateTime.

I tried like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LocalDateTime JAN_1_1970 = new LocalDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        DateTime local = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam"));
        DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);

        System.out.println("Europe/Amsterdam milis :" + new Duration(JAN_1_1970.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam")), local).getMillis());
        System.out.println("UTC  milis             :" + new Duration(JAN_1_1970.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC), utc).getMillis());

    }
```

And the result is;

```
Europe/Amsterdam milis :1429695646528
UTC  milis             :1429692046534
```

And @leonbloy write [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274902/jodatime-converting-time-zoned-date-time-to-millis) a good comment.

> Your local and utc represent the same instants of time, (only with
>   different timezones attached). Hence, getMillis() (which gives the
>   "physical" time interval elapsed from the "instant" corresponding to
>   the unix epoch), must return the same value.

I will also look for better solution with no constant.